# Is it possible to read all incoming Interactive Posts in Google+ API?

Tags: android, google-plus

G+ contains this nifty feature called Interactive Posts, which have resemblance to Facebook Shares.

It is possible to read interactive posts from an authorized user's page that were sent by users
of my application,
in a similar manner to the way you can read requests using Facebook Graph API?

ps. I'm talking about the Android API of Google+

Thanks beforehand,

Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the API does not provide you with the ability to read all of the [interactive posts](https://developers.google.com/+/features/interactive-posts) that are made from your app. The [activities.search method](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) would allow you to search for public posts, but it does not have the ability to filter the posts to those made by users from your app.

You can see aggregate data about interactive posts by using the [Google+ Insights feature](https://developers.google.com/+/features/analytics). But this is only going to give you very high level data.